# Split concave polygon in convex ones

Tags: polygon, computational-geometry

Is there any *easy* algorithm to split a concave polygon in convex ones or represent a polygon by triangles. I **know** there is a Wikipedia entry on triangulation but this doesn't really help me. I **know** there already is a question on Stackoverflow, however this is not very helpful to me. I would appreciate any pseudocode (or real code in an understandable programming language) to break a concave polygon in convex ones or triangles. Btw, the algorithm should also work for convex polygons and not mess around with them.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you represent the polygon? Do you know how to determine whether a vertex is convex or concave?

Comment: It's represented by n points by coordinates. Yes, all interior angles have to be less than 180 degrees to be a convex polygon.

Comment: So find a convex vertex (there must be some), and split it off as a triangle. {..., A, B, **C**, D, E, ...} => {..., A, B, D, E, ...} + {B, C, D}. Continue until all you have is triangles. This works for all polygons without holes, whether convex or concave.

Comment: I'd still have to test if the line new line by the triangle (B, D) crosses one of the polygon's edges, wouldn't I?

Comment: You're right, I hadn't thought of that. I'd better think this over some more...

Comment: Generally, I like your idea really much but since I would have to test n edges n times I'd have a quadratic runtime which wouldn't be that great :P

Comment: Why doesn't the Wikipedia article help you? Have you read about ear cutting? I think, it is exactly what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by the commenters, ear cutting (clipping) should be the most straight forward way to triangulate. To speed up the verifying process of an ear in practice one can employ a geometric grid.

To write robust and performant code, especially for geometric problems is very challenging. Why not use existing implementations like [triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) or [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/).

In order to use CGAL via python one could go for SWIG.